# How to save pictures when using SAVEITEM to new folder

Tags: imacros

Using this IMacros code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:"pagecontent_imgProduct" CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEITEM
```

How can i specify other folder for saving images, by default its saving to Imacros/Downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your line try to use [the 'ONDOWNLOAD' command](http://wiki.imacros.net/ONDOWNLOAD):

```
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=* ...
```